# Block matrices and tensor product notations.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensor-products, block-matrices

I know that $M_2(\mathbb{C})\otimes M_2(\mathbb{C})$ can be think of as $M_2(M_2(\mathbb{C}))$ as block matrix \begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\
C & D
\end{bmatrix}
with block matrices are multiplied just like matrix product. Similarly how can identify $M_2(\mathbb{C})\otimes M_2(\mathbb{C})^{op}$ interms of block matrices. As a vector spaces I think we can think of it as again block matrices. But I am confused of the product of two block matrices in this case?